# Find time complexity of $T(n)=3T(n-2)+O(n)$

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I try to find the time complexity of following recurrence relation:
$$T(n) = 3T(n-2) + O(n)$$
After subtitution,I get:
$$T(n)=3^{\frac{n}{2}}T(0)+\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}3^iO(n-2i)$$

I wonder if the ans is $O(3^{\frac{n}{2}})$ or $O(3^{\frac{n}{2}} n)$,
can someone give a help to determine the ans and give a proof about it.

Comment: Note that big-O stays correct if the right side is unnecessarily large. 3^(n/2) * n is unnecessarily large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrence relations do not have time complexities, algorithms do.

That said, assuming $T(1)=O(1)$ and $T(2)=O(1)$, both $T(n)=O(3^{n/2})$ and $T(n)=O(3^{n/2} n)$ are true. Indeed:
$$
T(n) = 3T(n-2)+O(n)
=3^i T(n-2i) + \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} 3^j O(n-2j)  \quad \text{for }i<n/2,
$$
choosing $i=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1 $:
$$
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 3^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1} \cdot O(1) + \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 2} 3^j O(n-2j) 
= O\left(  \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 2} 3^j (n-2j)  \right) \\
&= O\left(3^{n/2} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \right)
= O(3^{n/2}).
\end{align}
$$

Where we used the fact that each term of the summation increases by at least a factor of $2$ compared to the previous one. Indeed:
$$
\frac{3^{j+1} (n-2j-2)}{3^j (n-2j)} = 3\left(1-\frac{2}{n-2j}\right)
\ge 3\left(1-\frac{2}{n- 2(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 3)}\right) \ge 2.
$$

The above shows that $T(n) = O(3^{n/2})$, which also implies $T(n)=O(3^{n/2} n)$.